# How to center a plot within a grid using ggarrange() from the ggpubr package?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

Using ggarrange() from the "ggpubr" package, how can I create a grid where the last plot at the bottom is centered only in the bottom row?

Additionally, how can I share a single legend among the plots? In this setup, the plot 3 always has its independent legend if I change the `legend = "none"` to `common.legend = TRUE`.

```
# Packages
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

# Plots
plt.1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, colour = Species)) + 
  geom_point(size = 0.2) +
  theme(
    axis.ticks = element_line(size = 0.2),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 7),axis.text = element_text(size = 7),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
  )
plt.2 <- plt.1
plt.3 <- plt.1 

# Building a grid of plots
ggarrange(plt.1, plt.2, 
          ggarrange(plt.3, ncol = 1, legend = "none"), 
          nrow = 2,
          ncol = 2,
          legend = "none")

# Saving the image
ggsave("img.png", height = 6, width = 6, dpi = 300, bg = 'white')
```

[image]

I've been studying this topic for the past few hours, but I can only find examples where the top plot is centered and fills the entire first row. The script I sent is my latest unsuccessful attempt.

Below are the links I consulted:
https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/combine-multiple-ggplots-into-a-figure/
https://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/81-ggplot2-easy-way-to-mix-multiple-graphs-on-the-same-page/
[Aligning multiple plot in egg::ggarrange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60057291/aligning-multiple-plot-in-eggggarrange)

Comment: This is quite trivial to achieve using the patchwork package. Is there some reason you need to use ggarrange?

Comment: @Anderson, both `cowplot()` and `ggarrange()` offer straightforward means of doing this. See http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/81-ggplot2-easy-way-to-mix-multiple-graphs-on-the-same-page/. Cheer!

Comment: I did a large volume of work using ggpubr() imagining that this wouldn't be an impediment. In case I can't resolve it with that, I will be forced to readjust a lot of things. But I will take note of the suggestions given here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** I agree with the comments that `ggdraw()` or the `gridExtra` package ([good tutorial here](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/81-ggplot2-easy-way-to-mix-multiple-graphs-on-the-same-page/)) is a better way to go about this.

It's not pretty, but you can nest the `ggarrange()` functions and make use of blank plots to keep the grid. This helps with the limitation of only being able to specify `widths` or `heights` for entire columns or rows at a time.

```r
blank <- ggplot() + theme_void()

ggarrange(
    ggarrange(plt.1, plt.2, blank, nrow = 1,
        widths = c(1, 1, 0), legend = "none"),
    ggarrange(blank, plt.3, blank, nrow = 1,
        widths = c(0.5, 1, 0.5), legend = "none"),
    nrow = 2,
    legend = "none"
)
```

[image]

The `common.legend = TRUE` only seems to work within a single call to `ggarrange()`. But another odd workaround would be to extract the legends as their own ggplot objects. You could even stick these all together first with `ggarrange()`.

```r
p_legend <- as_ggplot(get_legend(plt.1))
```

Answer (score 1):

`library(gridExtra)`

```
layout_matrix <- matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
grid.arrange(plt.1, plt.2, plt.3, layout_matrix = layout_matrix)
```

Cheers, @Anderson!